# Prove that $\exists A \in Hom(V, W)$ such that $\dim (V_1) + \dim(W_1) = \dim(V)$ for some subspaces $V_1, W_1$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Let $\dim(V_1) + \dim(W_1) = \dim(V)$ for some subspaces $V_1 \leq V$ and $W_1 \leq W$. Prove that there exists a mapping $A \in Hom (V, W)$, such that $Im(A) = W_1$ and $\ker (A) = V_1$.

My plan is to create a mapping and then prove that it is linear.

I tried to make a mapping that maps to $W_1$. For example, $f: V_1 + W_1 \to W_1$, such that $v_1 + w_1 \mapsto w_1$. It is clear that $Im f = W_1$, but I'm not sure that $\ker f = V_1$.

Then I thought since I need $f \in Hom (V, W)$, then my mapping should map from $V$ to $W$, and I get stuck, because I don't know the image of $v \in V$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that $V_1$ and $W_1$ are not necessarily subspaces of the same vector space, so defining your map $f$ from domain $V_1 + W_1$ makes no sense. Even if $W_1$ and $V_1$ were subspaces of the same space, we do not necessarily have $V = V_1 \oplus W_1$.

Suppose that $\dim V_1 = k$ and $\dim V = n$. To that end, let $\{\mathbf{v}_1, \cdots , \mathbf{v}_k\}$ be any basis for $V_1$ and let us extend this basis to $\mathcal{B}=\{\mathbf{v}_1, \cdots ,\mathbf{v}_n\}$, a basis for $V$. Let $\{\mathbf{w}_1,\cdots,\mathbf{w}_{n-k}\}$ be any basis for $W_1$.

Now define the linear map $T:V\rightarrow V$ by its action on $\mathcal{B}$ as follows:
$$\begin{cases}T(\mathbf{v}_i) = \mathbf{0} & \text{for } 1\le i\le k,\\
T(\mathbf{v}_i) = \mathbf{w}_{i-k} & \text{for } k+1 \le i \le n.\end{cases}$$
Then $T$ is by construction a linear map with kernel $V_1$ and image $W_1$, as required.